# Multiple Frames inside a JFrame (Like our Netbeans and Eclipse!)

Tags: java, user-interface, iframe, jframe

I was googling around for a while looking to imitate what our usual applications have in their designs: **Multiple Frames** (if I got that correctly)

I was wondering how can I achieve the same thing? I get the concept of (assuming I was able to accomplish making them) having layouts and resize managers inside my frame so that everything will still fit, but how can I add frames inside a jframe? how can I attach, detach, resize, turn them into tabbed frames?

anyone got a lead I can start reading about?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a closer look at the Eclipse IDE source-code itself for example.

Find another starting point here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html

Comment: thanks for the heads up, now Im getting a bit of an idea how they made it. but Im not that good at reading complicated codes yet. got any possible snippets or samples?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a `cardLayout`, and those are not Multiple frames inside a frame, they're basically multiple `JPanel`s inside a JFrame.

When you use a `cardLyout` you can switch between panels inside your frame without needing to make another frame, this is very usefull and user-friendly compared to having multiple frames.

Comment: then what about their ability to resize? their ability to be moved around the frame?